# Azure Devops - Output Json Object from one task and Consume in another task

Tags: json, azure, powershell, azure-devops, yaml

Say I have a release pipeline in `Azure DevOps` written in `yaml` which has two tasks, one for reading json from a file and the second one for setting a key into a different json file using the json read in the first task. I have the following pipeline.yml -

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  name: ReadMetadataJson
  inputs:
    filePath: 'MetadataReader.ps1'
    arguments: 'Run MetadataReader.ps1 -pathToMetadata metadata.json'
- task: PowerShell@2
  name: SetAppSetting
  inputs:
    filePath: 'AppSettingSetter.ps1'
    arguments: 'Run AppSettingSetter.ps1 -pathToAppSetting SomeApp/Data.json -appSettingKey testkey -appSettingValue $($(ReadMetadataJson)).testkey'
- script: echo $(ReadMetadataJson.metadata)
```

Below are the Powershell scripts being called from each tasks -

**Powershell 1**

```
# Read From the Metadata.json
param ($pathToMetadata)

echo $pathToMetadata
$metadata = Get-content $pathToMetadata | out-string | ConvertFrom-Json

Write-Output "Metadata Json from metadata reader ps script - $metadata"
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=metadata;]$metadata"
```

**Powershell 2**

```
# For now just accept the values in parameter and log them
param ($pathToAppSetting, $appSettingKey, $appSettingValue)

echo "pathToAppSetting : $pathToAppSetting"
echo "appSettingKey : $appSettingKey"
echo "appSettingValue : $appSettingValue"

# Code to set in another file. I have this working, so omitting for brevity
```

And these are the json files -

**Metadata.json**

```
{
  "testkey": "TestValueFromMetadata",
  "testkey1": "TestValueFromMetadata1"
}
```

**appSetting.json**

```
{
  "testkey": "TestValueInAppSetting",
  "testkey1": "TestValueInAppSetting1"
}
```

The problem is when I want to return the json data as output from the first task and use it in the second task to pass the parameter to the second powershell script. Below is a screenshot of the pipeline result after I run it.

[image]

As can be seen, it says `ReadMetadataJson.metadata: command not found`. I have been following the [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#share-variables-across-pipelines) as a reference and have searched for other articles, but all I could find was handling values like `string` or `integer`, but not a `json` object. What is it that I am missing or doing wrong.

Comment: May I know how's the status of this before the weekend? Did you figure out this trouble now? Does my method is work for you?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT - Thank you for your answer. Though it kinda worked, but had some more scenarios coming in so came up with a different solution. May be I will include the structure in the question and then also provide my solution...

Comment: Sure! Looking forward to your solution shared:-)

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your JSON object to string (*ConvertTo-Json*) and pass it as variable to the second script.

Then on the second script, you just parse the string to JSON object again, using the *ConvertFrom-Json* method.

Answer (score 2):

Except the method that Hugo mentioned above, there has another solution can achieve what you want without any additional step added.

Just add one line into your `MetadataReader.ps1`:

```
param ($pathToMetadata)

echo $pathToMetadata
$metadata = Get-content $pathToMetadata | out-string | ConvertFrom-Json

$metadata | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | % { $o = $metadata.($_.Name); Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$($_.Name);isOutput=true]$o" }
```

Then, it will parse those json objects into corresponding variables after the json file contents get.

(*I make use of the work logic of terroform outputs here*)

---

Then you can directly use `{reference name}.{object name}` to call corresponding json value.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  name: ReadMetadataJson
  inputs:
    filePath: 'MetadataReader.ps1'
    arguments: 'Run MetadataReader.ps1 -pathToMetadata metadata.json'

- task: PowerShell@2
  name: SetAppSetting
  inputs:
    filePath: 'AppSettingSetter.ps1'
    arguments: 'Run AppSettingSetter.ps1 -pathToAppSetting Data.json -appSettingKey testkey -appSettingValue $(ReadMetadataJson.testkey)'

- script: echo $(ReadMetadataJson.testkey)
```

Note: I made changes here: `-appSettingValue $(ReadMetadataJson.testkey)`

[image]

Comment: Hi @Merlin Liang - I am just working on a similar use-case and happened to see your answer. It is useful . Can we make use variables values like $(ReadMetadataJson.testkey) only and not simply $(testkey). Is there a way to use the later one ?